# How to put image instead of text to product display on drupal commerce up

Tags: image, drupal, commerce

Is there any way to set as title to my product dispay on drupal commerce an image instead of a text title,I mean mostly on the frontpage of the website? Or even to be able to customize the product display? I am new to drupal commerce(commerce kickstart) and I bit of a help would be nice

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Product displays are regular Drupal nodes (pieces of content). Because of this, you can customize the product display the same way you would the display of any node type. Go to Structure » Content types (/admin/structure/types) and select "manage display" for the Product Display type(s). On this Manage Display page, you can customize the display for each available and selected view mode (default, full node, teaser, etc).

If you want more options when customizing the display of the view modes, check out the [Display Suite module](http://drupal.org/project/ds). Display Suite will upgrade the Manage Display pages to let you add layouts to your view modes, and the Display Suite Extras module (included, but must be enabled separately) will let you do advanced things like hiding the node's title in a display.